# Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ when $f(x)= \operatorname{sgn}(\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}))$ for all $x \in (0,1]$ and $f(0)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Help, I am having trouble showing that $f$ is riemann Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ when
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} \operatorname{sgn}\left(\sin\left((\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\right) & \text{if } x \in (0,1]  \\ 1 & \text{if } x = 0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: I started with sin (pi/x) =0  -> pi/x= npi and x= 1/n, n=1,2,3,..

Comment: Good. Now split the integral so that you integrate over the roots.

Comment: Do you know if you're supposed to prove it by definition? Do you have some other theorems about showing functions are integrable?

Comment: @user744868 The idea is to split the interval $(0,1)$ into subintervals $(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n+1})$ where the endpoints are two consecutive roots. This yields an alternating series which does converge.

Comment: I need to verify by using the following theorem: Let f:[a,b]->R be bounded. Then f is a Reimann Integrable on {a,b} iff for each e>0, there is a partition P such that U(P,f)-L(P,f)<= e.  (Sorry, I am not familiar with this editor for typing). Thanks. I am stuck verifying U(P,f)-L(P,f)<e using thus far analyzed statements. Thanks.

Comment: @ZiniahBeasley If you know Latex, you can just put Latex commands between `$` signs.

Comment: @user744868 Sure, sorry for that. But to me it seems a little bit uncommon that series aren’t addressed before Riemann integration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How should I finish verifying that U(P,f) - L(P,f) < e (epsilon)? Thanks again.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria Don't be sorry; I think it's a good suggestion. I agree that it's likely that Ziniah will know about convergent series, but it's not immediately obvious that the convergence of this series connects to Riemann integrability. There needs to be a theorem there. But, that said, I deleted my comment because I think your approach actually is rough direction we need to go; we just need to iron out the conclusion a bit.

Comment: @ZiniahBeasley As per EuklidAlexandria's suggestion, I would try making a partition out of the intervals $[1, 1/2], [1/2, 1/3], [1/3, 1/4], \ldots$. Now, there are an infinite number of these intervals, which is not permitted in the definition of the Riemann integral, but just end with a partition $[0, 1/n]$, i.e. take the first $n - 1$ intervals above, and add the $n$th interval to be $[0, 1/n]$. Then compute the upper and lower sums on this partition, and you should get a number that depends on $n$, and tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. This should answer your question.

Comment: This is the approach my professor provided, and I need to finish filling in the details using the theorem as mentioned above. I appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

Comment: Ah! Then this is the kind of thing that really should be included when asking a question on this site. Let's start with a specific example. Can you calculuate the upper/lower sums over the partition $[0, 1/3], [1/3, 1/2], [1/2, 1]$? Think about the minimum and maximum values of the function on these intervals.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, for the sake of simplifying the argument, I'm going to assume that the $\operatorname{sgn}$ function is undefined at $0$. Normally, it's defined to be $0$ at $0$, but this will spoil the simplicity of the argument. There is away around it, but it makes things much more complicated, and I doubt your professor took this into account when they gave you this exercise.

So, let's take the partition
$$P_n = \left\{\left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right], \left[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n-1}\right], \left[\frac{1}{n-1}, \frac{1}{n-2}\right] \ldots, \left[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}\right], \left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right]\right\}.$$
First thing to note is that $f(x)$ is constant on each interval, except the first interval. For $x \in \left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right]$, we have $\pi/x \in [\pi, 2\pi]$, hence $\sin(\pi/x) \le 0$, and thus $f(x) = -1$. For $x \in \left[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}\right]$, we have $\pi/x \in [2\pi, 3\pi]$, so $\sin(x) \ge 0$, and $f(x) = 1$. Each successive interval, until $\left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right]$, alternates $-1$ and $+1$ in this way.

On the interval $\left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right]$, on the other hand, $f$ achieves both $1$ and $-1$, and alternates between them.

Now, we calculuate $U(f, P_n)$ by computing the maximum value of $f$ on each of the intervals, multiply the result by the length of the interval, and sum these signed areas. We compute $L(f, P_n)$ similarly, taking the minimal value of $f$ on each interval instead.

But, note that $f$ is constant on each interval, except the first! That is, the upper sum and lower sum will agree on every interval, except the first interval. This means that, if we subtract $L(f, P_n)$ from $U(f, P_n)$, then all but one term will cancel: the term corresponding to the first interval $\left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right]$. So,
\begin{align*}
U(f, P_n) - L(f, P_n) &= \left(\max_{x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right]} f(x)\right) \times \frac{1}{n} - \left(\min_{x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right]} f(x)\right) \times \frac{1}{n} \\
&= 1 \times \frac{1}{n} - (-1) \times \frac{1}{n} = \frac{2}{n}.
\end{align*}
Because $\frac{2}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, there should be some $n$ such that $\frac{2}{n} < \varepsilon$. This tells us that $P_n$ is the partition you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! It makes sense and very helpful.

Comment: Very nice answer! Sorry for being nitpicky, but we have to actually show this for an arbitrary partition as well.

Comment: @EuklidAlexanria Not necessarily, see Ross excercise 32.6